# how to load csv data in Python 3 using Jupyter

Tags: python, csv, jupyter, python-idle

I am trying to import data from a `csv` file using Jupyter. I am new to Python.
It works fine in IDLE, but not in Jupyter.

```
import csv
with open("mpg.txt","r") as mpgFile:
    mpgFileReader = csv.reader(mpgFile)
    mpgList = []
    for row in mpgFileReader:
        if len (row)!=0:
            mpgList = mpgList + [row]
mpgFile.close()
print(mpgList)
```

---

#### This is the error I receive

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-42823a11b1d0> in <module>()
      1 import csv
----> 2 with open("mpg.txt","r") as mpgFile:
      3     mpgFileReader = csv.reader(mpgFile)
      4     mpgList = []
      5     for row in mpgFileReader:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mpg.txt'
```

I also tried to specify the full path of the file:

```
"C:\Users\serdi\Documents\Test\mpg.txt"
```

But then it gives me another error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-61-fed3bca4876a>", line 2
    with open("C:\Users\serdi\Documents\Test\mpg.txt","r") as mpgFile:
             ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original problem is likely as you surmised, namely the path is incorrect.  However the second error is due to the `\` in the 
`"C:\Users\serdi\Documents\Test\mpg.txt"`  The `\` is an escape.  There are at least three alternatives.

**Use a raw string:**

```
with open(r"C:\Users\serdi\Documents\Test\mpg.txt","r") as mpgFile:
```

note the `r` in front of the string.

**Escape the `\`:**

```
with open("C:\\Users\\serdi\\Documents\\Test\\mpg.txt","r") as mpgFile:
```

**Use '/' instead of `\`:**

```
with open("C:/Users/serdi/Documents/Test/mpg.txt","r") as mpgFile:
```

Comment: You can include `Pathlib`

Comment: @pylang, how does pathlib help with the munged string?

Comment: You can include `Pathlib.Path`, improved in Python 3.6 https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-519-adding-a-file-system-path-protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I used ("C:\Users\JOHN-PC\Videos\ml-twitter-sentiment-analysis-develop\data\twitter_train.csv") for load twitter data set. I always got problem  in python 3 .

Comment: always use \\ .